# VBScript to rename multiple Files using CSV file

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have 500 video files in a folder and I want all of them to be renamed. I'm using CSV file that has two columns with both old and new names. I tried this code and it gives me an error. Can someone help me to fix this code or help me with a new code.

```
Option Explicit     
Dim objFile, strLine    
Dim objFSO, aline, i  
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
Set objFile= objFSO.OpenTextFile("List.csv", 1)     

Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream     
strLine = objFile.readline     
aline = Replace(strLine,",",""", """)               

i = """" & aline & """"  

FSO.MoveFile & i

Loop


objFile.Close
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the error.

Comment: First look: `FSO.MoveFile " & i` - that lonely double quote can't be correct.

Comment: Second look: you don't have a variable named `FSO` only `objFSO`.

Comment: That double quote is a typing mistake I've done when I post that. just re-corrected that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not batch?

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A IN ('TYPE List.csv') DO ( 
IF EXIST %%A ( 
REN %%A %%B
) ELSE (
ECHO %%A NOT FOUND!!!
)
)
```

Comment: I think that batch has a more simple syntax in this case.

Comment: Just teasing (the OP) - batch looks really slick here.

Comment: Piotr Truszkowski

that batch code isn't working. it says that the syntax is incorrect.

OS is windows 10

Comment: Filburt: 
powershell is ok. but I'm not familiar with powershell. So I tried VBS.

Comment: @KLM you've ran it from a batch file or directly from command line?

Comment: @PiotrTruszkowski

I ran it from a batch file.